# Make one view center as buttom of second view in Auto Layout - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

There are two views- I want to show green view of the background image with center align to the buttom of image as shown in below image

[image]

Green view height will also be dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just constrain the centerY anchor of the greenView to the bottom anchor of the image view:

```
greenView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
greenView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: Really thankful to you :)